# База данных Python

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос при заносе данных в бд postgresql. Скрипт парсит номера телефонов с текста на сайте. Вот сайт: https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx?Date=04-May-2020 . Заносит их в список. При попытке засунуть их в бд, возникает ошибка:

нужно засунуть эти номера телефонов в "live_call_number". Заранее большое спасибо!
Вот сама БД:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут `res.append(str(elem) + str(*arr[el + 1].split(',')))` что это за звездочка? `*arr`

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO numbers (live_call_number) VALUES ({0});".format(str(i)))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Добавляю в список вторую часть телефона. Переменная elem = (800), а arr[el + 1].split(',') = остальной части номера телефона. Так как есть сплит, получается список (список второй части номера телефона). А звездочка убирает этот список и в итоге добавляет в список res

Comment: И тогда в списке res у меня строка в виде полноценного номера телефона (телефон - строка (str))

Comment: Не могу так сказать "синхронизировать" скипт и бд, ругается пайчарм. Попробовал исправить, но заметил, что в live_call_number у меня пусто, то есть ничего нет

Comment: И при этом пытаюсь туда засунуть номер телефона, хотя вставлять эти данные некуда. Вот доработка, но не работает: cursor.execute("insert into live_call_number (phone_num) values (%s)")

Comment: phone_num - значение в таблице, которое должно быть. Но как создать это в таблице? Значение: varchar []

Comment: varchar это строка, можно положить весь номер целиком если у него тоже тип строка, может ругается потому что вы туда хотите засунуть число?

Comment: a = get_link(get_html('https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx?Date=04-May-2020'))
for i in a:
    print(type(i))
написано класс str

Comment: тогда еще возможно у вас ограничение по символам, проверьте сколько приходит символов и сколько можно записать в БД

Comment: А как проверить, сколько символов можно засунуть в бд?

Comment: В pgadmin можно открыть таблицу и там будет varchar(n)  то что в скобках и есть количество символов

Comment: Фото приложил в основной текст

Comment: Попробуйте execute заменить на эту строку `"INSERT INTO numbers (live_call_number) VALUES ({0})".format(str(i))`

Comment: Ошибки не вылетели, но в бд ничего не отображается

Comment: Где увдеть результат? Ни в live_call_number, нигде не отображаются эти номера (

Comment: Как мне в самой бд их увидеть?

Comment: Может соединился с базой неверно? Вообще в другие таблицы или столбцы из питона записывает? П.с. ещё в конце надо точку с запятой ставить ; в execute